# For $a\geq 0$, when does the integral $\int_0^{1/e}\frac{1}{x^a|\log x|^{2a}}\, dx$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

My notes actually say that for $a\geq 0$, we have $\int_0^{1/e}\frac{1}{x^a|\log x|^{2a}}\, dx < \infty \iff a\leq 1$.

Now I can't see why this may be the case. I think I can prove the "$\impliedby$" direction:

Since $\int_0^{1/e}\frac{1}{x|\log x|^2}\, dx = -\frac{1}{\log x}\Big|^{1/e}_0 =1 < \infty$, then the converse direction easily follows by comparison test.

How might one do the forwards direction?

Comment: Assume that $a>1$, then bound the integrand from below by $C x^{-a+\varepsilon}$ for some suitable $\varepsilon>0$ and some constant $C>0$ and get that the integral in question is infinite.

Comment: Use the substitution $x=e^{-t}$